# Is it possible to create a checkbox with images along with the text in the labels in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Somebody please give me ideas on this!I would like to generate multiple checkboxes with an image along with the text in the label. I have created a field called solutioncheckbox in the Contact form for Checkbox. My code is as below for creating multiple Checkboxes

```
<?php echo $this->Form>input('solutioncheckbox',array('label'=>false,'type'=>'select','class'=>'solution','multiple'=>'checkbox','options'=>array(1=>'WEB DESIGN',2=>'WEB DEVELOPMENT',3=>'GRAPHICS DESIGN'))) ;?>
```

Can I create an image  along with the text in each of the labels like WEB DESIGN,WEB DEVELOPMENT etc in my form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the job done for you ;)

```
echo $this->Form->input
    (
        'Model.field',
        array
        (
            'multiple' => 'checkbox',
            'options' => array('1' => $this->Html->image('cake.icon.png') . 'Text beside the image', '2' => $this->Html->image('test-error-icon.png') . 'Other text beside the image'),
            'escape' => FALSE
        )
);
```